# How to pass a variable number of non-contiguous buffers to a kernel

Tags: c++, opencl

I have a set (of a non-deterministic length) of non-contiguous cl buffers of the same size in a `std::vector<cl::Buffer>`. I would like to do a per-pixel reduction (in this case, multiplication) of some kind across the buffers. The only two methods I have come up with (both which seem to have unnecessary overhead/is completely and totally unreadable)

1. Call the kernel multiple times.
2. Copy all the buffers to contiguous memory.
3. Programatically write the kernel function:

like so

```
int num_values = 4;
std::stringstream kernel;
kernel << 
"__global void pix_reduce_"<<num_values<<
"  (int out*,int* a1";

for (int i = 1; i < num_values; i++)
    kernel << ",int* a"<<i;
kernel << ",int numel)" <<
"{"<<
"  const int global_idx= get_global_id(0);"<<
"  if (global_idx<numel)"<<
"  {"<<
"    int out_val = 1;";
for (int i = 0; i < num_values; i++)
  kernel << "out_val*=a"<<i<<"[global_idx];";
kernel << "out[global_idx]=out_val;}}";
```

All of these methods kinda stink. Calling the kernel multiple times adds the kernel call overhead over and over again. Copying the buffer is completely unnecessary work. Writing the kernel is just completely unreadable and would require extra overhead on every new count. How do you get around this?

Comment: I think a good formatting alone would make a lot better if nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the length of each buffer, and all of them are equal.
Then why don't rewrite it like this:

Host side:

```
//Use one struct to organize the data
struct MyStruct{
    cl_int values[10];
    // ...
};

//Create one only cl::Buffer of N elements of type MyStruct
cl::Buffer mybuff = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, in_size * sizeof(MyStruct));

//Run the kernel
```

Device side:

```
//Use one struct to organize the data
typedef struct{
    int values[10];
    // ...
}MyStruct;

__global void pix_reduce
  (MyStruct out*, MyStruct* in)
{
   // ...
}
```

You can even define the length "10" to X, and put that define in your code (host and CPU side). Another good option is one BIG array of contiguous memory and pass the seperation length to the kernel.

NOTE: I know it is hard to stop using pointers, but thats the price to pay because the memory zones are different. And belive me, I have done VERY complex dynamic length structs, and with a little thinking and rewrite, it gets to work, and the code is quite tidy.

**EDIT: Another solution that can change dynamically**

Host side:

```
//Data organized as jagged array
std::vector<std::vector<cl_int> > my_data;

//It is supposed to be filled my_Data
//....

//Create one only cl::Buffer of NxM elements of type int
cl::Buffer mybuff = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, my_data.size() * my_data[0].size() * sizeof(cl_int));
cl::Buffer mybuff_out = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, my_data.size() * my_data[0].size() * sizeof(cl_int));

// Copy the jagged array
for(int i=0; i<my_data.size(); i++)
queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(mybuff, CL_FALSE, i * my_data[0].size() * sizeof(cl_int), my_data[0].size() * sizeof(cl_int), &my_data[i][0]);

//Set kernel
kernel.SetArgs(0, mybuff);
kernel.SetArgs(1, mybuff_out);
kernel.SetArgs(2, (cl_int)my_data[0].size());

//Run the kernel
queue.EnqueueNDRangeKernel(...);
```

Device side:

```
__kernel void pix_reduce
  (_global const int * in, _global int * out, const int size)
{
     unsigned int id = get_global_id(0);
     for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
          out[id*size+i] = out[id*size+i]; //Or any other operation using size as the separation between chunks
     }
}
```

Comment: I know the length at run-time, not compile time, and the source buffers are not coming from the same "place" (i.e. different modules), and are on the order of 3 or 4 megapixels rather than small values. I am trying to write it in a scalable way, such that we can add more of these buffers on later with minimal changes to the code base and small overhead. The way i've done it in Cuda is to use a jagged array (which can either be loaded into private memory or local memory), but with the lack of pointer math opencl just simply doesn't seem to be able to support anything of the kind.

Comment: I updated my answer, see if that may be of some use. Everything is dynamic, and you can selectively rewrite the data using EnqueueWriteBuffer and an offset value.

Comment: Yeah, copying the jagged array into contiguous memory is option #2. It just is slow and an unnecessary copy.

Comment: But then I am missing something here. If you need those data in GPU to operate with them, either way you will have to copy to GPU. Even in CUDA, the copy has to be performed. The only solution would be to minimize the cases of copy if the information has not changed.

Comment: The data is already on the GPU, created by a series of different GPU methods. The unnecessary copy is the copy from a collection of non-contiguous GPU buffers to a contiguous GPU buffer.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Then it is a different problem. Can you change the output of those methods? What do they output? Maybe you can just call a series of enqueueCopyBuffer(). That will copy the memory from your output to the contiguous buffer, probably it will be fast, since the copy is from device->device.

Comment: You can also create first the contiguous buffer, and generate a set of subbuffers, then use these subbuffers as output to the other kernels. And you will have your memory tidy without any need to copy.